# Configurable products - Attribute options are available although they are not applicable

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product

I have a configurable product in magento P which has 3 associated attributes - thickness,size, color.
I created associated associated products like:

P1-> Thickness 1mm, - size S, - Color green
P2-> Thickness 1mm, - size S, - Color red
P3-> Thickness 1mm, - size S, - Color blue

P4-> Thickness 1mm, - size M, - Color green
P5-> Thickness 1mm, - size M, - Color red

P6-> Thickness 2mm, - size S, - Color green
P7-> Thickness 2mm, - size S, - Color blue
P8-> Thickness 2mm, - size S, - Color red
P9-> Thickness 2mm, - size S, - Color purple

Size, color and thickness are all drop downs- thickness comes first, then size and then color.

When the user chooses Thickness as 2 mm, the size M should not be available for the user to select. But with my current configuration it is.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you check the console log if there's any errors?
Also, are you 100% sure that you didn't add a product that has Thickness as 2 mm and Size as M?